# Get user information in 2 factor authentication template in Umbraco 8

Tags: c#, cookies, owin, two-factor-authentication, umbraco8

I am implementing 2FA for users in Umbraco 8 and after logging in but before entering a code, I need to do some check ups. For this check up I need to know which user is logged in and I cannot figure out how I can get to know which user is logged in.

After a user is logged in in the backoffice, I show a html template, which is made possible by this line of code:

```
public string GetTwoFactorView(IOwinContext owinContext, UmbracoContext umbracoContext, string username) =>
        PackageConstants.PathToMfaHtmlTemplate;
```

The template is linked to an angularjs controller:

```
<div ng-controller="mfaLoginController" class="umb-login-container">
  //...
</div>
```

In my controller I got access to the services:

```
userService
authResource
```

but both doesn't seem to have the user data in it. Is there another service I can inject here which can provide me the user data?

From this controller I need to make API calls to an Umbraco API:

```
[IsBackOffice, PluginController("LoginMfa")]
public class MfaLoginApiController : UmbracoApiController
{
     //...
}
```

In an endpoint I have managed to retrieve the OWIN TwoFactorCookie with the next line of code:

```
var mfaCookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies(".AspNet.UmbracoTwoFactorCookie").FirstOrDefault()
                .Cookies.FirstOrDefault(cookie => cookie.Name == ".AspNet.UmbracoTwoFactorCookie").Value;
```

This returns a what looks like encrypted string. Is there a way to decrypt this string and get the user data (user Id is enough) from this cookie, if it is stored in this cookie at all?

Or is there a better way to retrieve the user at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. While investigating a possible different solution for my problem, I saw the next code in AuthenticatorController of Umbraco (very nice it is open source):

```
private BackOfficeSignInManager _signInManager;

private BackOfficeSignInManager SignInManager => _signInManager ?? (_signInManager = TryGetOwinContext().Result.GetBackOfficeSignInManager());
```

Fortunately, I am able to use this code too in my API controller and this line of code gave me what I need.

```
var userId = await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync();
```